# matplotlib Patches - Extracting the containing information

Tags: python, matplotlib

so I am working with a Python package (Pycalphad) which uses matplotlib.patches for plotting the legend of diagrams. These patches contain the colors and respective labels.

In the package, the entries are defined as `(mpatches.Patch(color=colorlist[phase], label=phase))`, with `phase` being a changing variable.

If I wanna read one of the legend entries, I only get back *<matplotlib.patches.Patch at 0x14e5373f108>*.
I would prefer not to change the code of the package and rather work with what I got.
So is there a way to extract the information contained in the Patches and getting the colors and labels used in the definition of the patch?
Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`get_...` methods of Patch](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.get_ec) to access the properties you want:

```py
from matplotlib import patches

my_patch = patches.Patch(color='red', label='my_patch')

my_patch.get_fc()  # this is the facecolor
Out[4]: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

my_patch.get_ec()  # this is the edgecolor
Out[5]: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

my_patch.get_label()  # and the label
Out[6]: 'my_patch'
```

---

So in this example `my_patch` is the object that gives *<matplotlib.patches.Patch at 0x7fea0290d518>* if I simply write `my_patch` in the console.

Comment: That was surprisingly easy, weird I could not find that somewhere. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jusles You are welcome! Luckily not everything in `matplotlib` is complicated. :) Like many other things, also the documentation of matplotlib takes some getting used to.